# stuck on "enabled billing"

Tags: google-app-engine

I missed hitting one of those last "proceed to checkout" buttons.  I found the tab and hit submit but it had timed out and did not let me re-submit.  Now my app has been stuck (disabled) for over an hour still waiting for the credit card to be approved.  There is no way to re-try.  Do you think Google should improve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Billing FAQ](https://developers.google.com/appengine/kb/billing) entry for "I have a question related to billing that isn't addressed here. Where can I get an answer?" suggests you should contact support:

> If you have a billing issue or question that isn't explicitly answered in the FAQ entries above, please [contact support](http://www.google.com/support/enterprise/go/support_info#cloud) and a Google representative will respond to you shortly. Customers that have enabled billing can get direct help from Google on billing issues. Operational support is only available to Premier customers.

Comment: Thank you.. I was a little panicked at the time...  Maybe this will help someone else.  I did see something about non-premier customers not having access to phone support.  This must have been technical assistance and did not apply to billing issues.